# Artemis ActiveMQ + MDB long time work: how long it wait before redelivery

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have Wildfly 21.0.0 with a jms-queue configured and a couple of in-vm connector/acceptor.
Then I have a Message Driven Bean (MDB) with 5 max concurrent sessions than handle messages received and do some dirty work.
In some cases the work takes longer than 5 minutes and it happens that the queue redeliver the message to the MDB, causing a mess.

I understood the redelivery concepts, redelivery delay, ..., but I don't find any documentation about how long Artemis ActiveMQ waits before declaring that the message that is in delivering state (waiting the auto-acknowledge at the end of the onMessage method long execution) must be redelivered.
From logs I think it waits 5 minutes, then redeliver the message after 2 seconds of redelivery delay.

Is this time configurable?

Thanks!

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
            <server name="default">
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-acceptor>
                <jms-queue name="MyJobsQueue" entries="java:/jms/MyJobsQueue" />
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="none" pre-acknowledge="true"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "MyJobsQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "5")
})
public class MyJobsListener implements MessageListener {

    //new logger.....
    
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message m) {
        try {
            logger.info("Received message ({}) (Redelivered:{})", m.getJMSMessageID(), m.getJMSRedelivered());
            
            Thread.sleep(10 * 60 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

```
2020-11-19 04:00:00 INFO - Received message (ID:5002ad76-2a13-11eb-bedf-005056b94ad2)  (Redelivered:false)
2020-11-19 04:05:00 INFO - Received message (ID:5002ad76-2a13-11eb-bedf-005056b94ad2)  (Redelivered:true)
2020-11-19 04:10:00 INFO - Received message (ID:5002ad76-2a13-11eb-bedf-005056b94ad2)  (Redelivered:true)
2020-11-19 04:15:00 INFO - Received message (ID:5002ad76-2a13-11eb-bedf-005056b94ad2)  (Redelivered:true)
2020-11-19 04:45:24 INFO - Received message (ID:5002ad76-2a13-11eb-bedf-005056b94ad2)  (Redelivered:true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDBs (just like all other kinds of EJBs) implicitly support JTA transactions and as soon as the MDB receives a message a transaction is started by the container. This is done so that any transactional work (e.g. updating a database, sending another JMS message, etc.) done while processing the message will be a part of the transaction for consuming the message itself. In this way a message can be a "unit of work."

It is therefore important to note that the default transaction timeout in WildFly is 300 seconds (i.e. 5 minutes). Once the transaction times-out the message will be rolled-back onto the queue and potentially redelivered. How redelivery works depends ultimately on the broker's configuration, of course.

In any case, you can prevent this kind of issue for long-running MDBs by disabling JTA transactions with this annotation:

```java
@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

If you don't want to disable container-managed transactions for the MDB you can change the default transaction timeout by adding the `default-timeout` attribute to the `coordinator-environment` element in `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:5.0">`, e.g.:

```xml
<coordinator-environment statistics-enabled="${wildfly.transactions.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}" default-timeout="600"/>
```

However, keep in mind that long-running transactions are an anti-pattern so I would discourage you from increasing the timeout.

Comment: Ok, so the 5 min timeout id inherited from JTA, good! And thank you for your suggestion to disable transaction management.But what if I want to let the container manage the transaction? Is it possible to increase the wildfly transaction timeout? Is it a good idea? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Did my answer address your comment? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who run into this problem in the future. If so, please elaborate as to what's still lacking. Thanks!

Comment: In addition, if the intention is to manage the transaction manually, it is possibile to use
     @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154142/java-ee-transactionmanagement-bean-how-does-it-combine-with-container-managed